# Series Summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Consider the given sum.

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{x^n}{[(2n+1)!]^3} = ?$$ Does there exist a closed form of the above summation. What is the general procedure to perform such a sum ? I tried writing the above in terms of hypergeometrics but wasn't very successful. Any ideas

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Can you take a crack at this ?

Comment: Wolfram says the answer is ${}_0F_5(;1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;\frac x{64})$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah, that is what I got, but I am looking for a slightly simpler answer, you know in terms of sin, cos etc. Thank you anyway.

Comment: There is a high chance such series is algebraically independent from $\sin(1)$ and $\cos(1)$. Such further generalization of Bessel functions is horribly fast-convergent, why do you need an explicit representation in terms of "standard" functions? I won't bet on its existence.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh, I was just expecting a simpler answer, because it looked like cube of the terms in the power series of sin.

Comment: @user44690: in general $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n^3$ has little to do with $\left(\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n\right)^3$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh, I was just hoping against hope. Research sometimes make you do that. Sorry, to have wasted your time.

Comment: In the future, the responses will be more helpful to you if you include, in the original question, information like "I already found this specific expression ... in terms of hypergeometric functions, but I am hoping for something simpler in terms of sin and cos...." Think of how much easier it is for us to give you feedback that is actually useful to you if we don't have to elicit this information through a series of comments.

Comment: @GregMartin Indeed ? The original question is show that the three-point function of the fermionic spin-0 current in supersymmetric theory is related to the bosonic spin-0 current in regular bosonic theory multiplied by the two-point function of the fermionic spin-0 current in regular fermionic theory three times and by an over all function of the coupling. The question I asked after pages and pages of computation reduces to the one I asked.

Comment: @GregMartin $$\langle \mathcal{O}_f\mathcal{O}_f\mathcal{O}_f\rangle_{SUSY} =\langle \mathcal{O}_b\mathcal{O}_b\mathcal{O}_b\rangle_{RB}\langle \mathcal{O}_f\mathcal{O}_f\rangle^3_{RF} f(\lambda)$$ find $f(\lambda)$. $f(\lambda)$ is related to the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ratio of consecutive terms:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{x}{(2n+2)^3(2n+3)^3}=\frac{x/64}{(n+1)^3(n+\frac32)^3}$$

with $a_0=1$, and hence, the series is given by the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{[(2n+1)!]^3}={}_0F_5\left(;1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;\frac x{64}\right)$$

I doubt there is anything one can do here, save for possibly some special values (that I wouldn't know of). In general, converting a series such as this to a generalized hypergeometric function simply amounts to computing the ratio of consecutive terms and factoring the numerator and denominator, and extra constants go into the last argument.